# Updating an entity with Entity Framework 4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

Here is the code I'm using to create a new Student.

```
public class StudentRepository
{
    SchoolEntities db = new SchoolEntities();

    public IQueryable<Student> FindAllStudents()
    {
        return db.Students;
    }

    public Student FindStudent(int id)
    {
        return db.Students.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ID == id);
    }

    public void Add(Student Student)
    {
        db.AddToStudents(Student);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Here's how I'm using it:

```
private void SaveInformation()
{
    Student student = new Student();
    Int64 gradeId = Convert.ToInt64(cmbGradeParalelo.SelectedValue);
    student.IDGrade = gradeId;
    student.RUDE = Convert.ToInt64(txtRude.Text);

    /*Parents information.*/
    student.FatherName = txtNombrePadre.Text;
    student.FatherProfession = txtProfesionPadre.Text;
    student.MobilePhoneFather = FormatPhoneNumber(txtCelularPadre.Text);
    student.PlaceofWorkFather = txtLugarDeTrabajoPadre.Text;

    student.MotherName = txtNombreMadre.Text;
    student.MotherProfession = txtProfesionMadre.Text;
    student.MobilePhoneMother = FormatPhoneNumber(txtCelularMadre.Text);
    student.PlaceofWorkMother = txtLugarDeTrabajoMadre.Text;

    /*Student information*/
    student.Name = txtNombre.Text;
    student.FatherLastName = txtApellidoPaterno.Text;
    student.MotherLasteName = txtApellidoMaterno.Text;
    student.DateOfBirth = dtpFechaNacimiento.Value.ToShortDateString();
    student.PlaceOfBirth = txtLugarNacimiento.Text;
    student.Sex = sexoMasculino.Checked ? sexoMasculino.Text : sexoFemenino.Text;
    student.Telephone = FormatPhoneNumber(txtTelefono.Text);
    student.MobilePhone = FormatPhoneNumber(txtCelular.Text);
    student.Address = txtDireccion.Text;
    student.Carnet = FormatPhoneNumber(txtCarnet.Text);
    student.Observations = txtObservaciones.Text;

    StudentRepository repo = new StudentRepository();
    repo.Add(student);
    repo.Save();
    MessageBox.Show("Se guardo el registro exitosamente.",
        "Exito!",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
        MessageBoxIcon.Information,
        MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
    ClearForm();
}
```

The problem is when I load the information on a form, and hit the save again, a new Student is created. I'd like to modify the students information.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *easiest* solution would be to get the Student first, then make the changes.

```
var existingStudent = StudentRepository.FindStudent(1); // object now in EF graph
student.RUDE = Convert.ToInt64(txtRude.Text); // object now set to EntityState.Modified
// other fields
repo.Save(); // object saved to database
```

On a side note, don't do this:

```
db.AddToStudents(Student);
```

The recommended way in EF4 is:

```
db.Students.AddObject(Student);
```

By the looks of the code, i'm guessing this is either a WinForms or WPF app? Maybe your better of using a control with [EntityDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/Video/cc546554), as opposed to the painstaking task of manually updating the model.

Comment: What's the difference  between the two different ways of adding?

Comment: @Sergio: Functionally nothing, but one is deprecated (and will eventually be removed from the framework). For new code, you should go with the recommended version.

Comment: Yes but here, you're performing an unnecessary select request.
If you were not using EF, this would not be necessary, an ID would be enough. Is there a way to act the same without the select ?

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new `Student` instance yourself whenever you click save. That's correct if you want to create a new `Student` record, but if you want to edit an existing record, you will have to modify a `Student` record that you've retrieved from the database instead.

A better OO approach would be to have the calling form pass the `Student` object to your student editor form. This way, the calling form would instantiate a new `Student` object itself if creating a new one, then if the `DialogResult` of the form is `OK`, add it to the context and save it. In the case of opening an existing record, the calling form would pass the existing `Student` record to the editor, then call `Save()` once it closes.

On an unrelated note, you really need to `Dispose` of the context once you're done with it.

Comment: How do I dispose the context?

Comment: @Sergio: Call `Dispose()` on the instance of the context. If you really want to use this pattern you have (where you have a class that encapsulates the context), the best idea would be to make your class implement `IDisposable`, then create a function in it called `Dispose()` that calls `db.Dispose()`. Then, whenever you use your class in your code, enclose it in a `using` block.